# i2c digital audio stream as input in linux audio

Tags: linux, audio, driver, i2c

At the moment i have an A/D (analog to digital converter) that i am using to convert an analog audio stream to digital to put into the computers audio system via I2C. The end goal is, is to take the digital stream and pump it through the I2C bus to a Computer running Debian Linux, which will then receive it as an audio input to be either modified (effects done to the audio) or just output as if it was say a MIC input of the computer.

At the moment i am not to sure where to start with this in linux. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I haven't done anything with setting up the I2C output stream of the digital audio yet since I do not have knowledge of how the data needs to be interpreted on the linux side.

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: What sample rate, sample bit size, and stereo/mono?  Is this a basic ADC or a real audio codec chip that uses I2S?  If you are doing just I2C to a basic ADC without some additional hardware support, you will probably run into realtime issues.

Comment: As of what was decided today.. It will be an Atmega Micro using the 10 Bit ADC for the sampling and it will be mono. This way other functions can be handled serially. We are wanting to maximize the most out of the bit rate as possible and to get no less that 32k if possible... We may move to the UART for the sending of the ADC as well, but we are not fully sure which would be easier at this time.